# LateInitializationError: Field 'currentLatLng' has not been initialized in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, location

I am displaying my current location on google maps using this library: `package:location/location.dart`. [Pub Dev Link](https://pub.dev/packages/location)

The problem is whenever I open the app in **release mode** it crashes and shows:

> LateInitializationError: Field 'currentLatLng' has not been
> initialized

It does not crash in **debug mode** on an Android Device.
It does, however, crash on iOS **(release and debug mode)**.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here's my widget and attempt:

```dart
    class TestGoogle extends StatefulWidget {
      const TestGoogle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      _TestGoogleState createState() => _TestGoogleState();
    }

    class _TestGoogleState extends State<TestGoogle> {
      late LatLng currentLatLng;
      late GoogleMapController mapController;
      Location location = new Location();
      var latitude;
      var longitude;
      late LocationData _locationData;
      get() async {
        _locationData = await location.getLocation();
        latitude = _locationData.latitude;
        longitude = _locationData.longitude;
        setState(() {
          currentLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        });
      }
      @override
      initState() {
        super.initState();
        get();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: GoogleMap(
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            onCameraMove: (CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
              print(cameraPosition.zoom);
            },
            initialCameraPosition:
                CameraPosition(target: currentLatLng, zoom: 15.0),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have fixed up your question, spelling syntax, etc. Have you tried running the verbose output with flutter run -v --release? Please include the output of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below codes should fix your problem. Your problem reason, try use variable before initializing.

```dart
class TestGoogle extends StatelessWidget {
  TestGoogle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  Location location = Location();

  Future<LatLng> get() async {
    final _locationData = await location.getLocation();
    return LatLng(_locationData.latitude, _locationData.longitude);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<LatLng>(
        future: get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final locationModel = snapshot.data!;
            final latitude = locationModel.latitude;
            final longitude = locationModel.longitude;

            return GoogleMap(
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              onCameraMove: (CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                print(cameraPosition.zoom);
              },
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: locationModel, zoom: 15.0),
            );
          }
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a question, when i open this in Android then it open very fast but if i open this in iOS physical device then it open very slow (shows circular progress indicator).

Comment: It's interesting problem, maybe if you connect the internet with ethernet cable on computer so fast connection and ios device wi-fi connection slow relative to the other

Comment: So how i can solve this in iOS devices?

Comment: Have you ever tried an iOS emulator?

Comment: In simulator i have to put hardcoded latitude and latitude on simulator settings so limitation of using the simulator. And yes if i put hardcoded latitude and longitude both in simulator or in code then it is working fine.

Comment: I think it is wifi connection problem, your wifi connection may be slow

Comment: Same wifi connection i am using in android device it is working fine.
I also checked in mobile data in iOS physical device but same problem

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed this by

```
class TestGoogle extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestGoogle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _TestGoogleState createState() => _TestGoogleState();
}

class _TestGoogleState extends State<TestGoogle> {
  LatLng? currentLatLng;
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  Location location = new Location();
  var latitude;
  var longitude;
  late LocationData _locationData;
  get() async {
    _locationData = await location.getLocation();
    latitude = _locationData.latitude;
    longitude = _locationData.longitude;
    setState(() {
      currentLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    });
  }
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    get();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: currentLatLng == null
          ? Center(child: PlatformCircularProgressIndicator())
          : GoogleMap(
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        onCameraMove: (CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
          print(cameraPosition.zoom);
        },
        initialCameraPosition:
            CameraPosition(target: currentLatLng, zoom: 15.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).